# Как правильно поставить ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: д**е**ды и прад**е**ды или дед**ы** и прад**е**ды?

Comment: мне кажется, выделение ударения жирным шрифтом выглядит неочевидным. не понимаю, зачем это делать, когда в юникоде специально для обозначения ударения есть соответствующий символ?! кроме того, выделение вариантов написания в отдельные цитаты делает их более читаемыми.

Comment: заголовок вопроса должен быть информативным и содержать его суть

Answer (score 3):

Правильно:

> де́ды и пра́деды.

Деды́ - это только в переносном значении (старослужащие и вообще всякие ветераны-старожилы).
А вот как Вы додумались до ударения "праде́ды" науке неизвестно.

Comment: Хорошо хоть не дедЫ и прадедЫ )))

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

> де́ды и пра́деды,

но в относительных прилагательных ударение одинаковое:

> де́довский и праде́довский.